# Prototype with jQuery

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I had almost the same question a couple of days ago about JavaScript not running inside of Prototype windows.
The solution was attaching "window." to the function name and it worked, Now I'm trying to do the same for jQuery but with no success.

Here is the working JavaScript Code:

```
window.show_confirm = function(id)
```

Here is the jQuery example i want to work:

```
jQuery('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
        if (this.value == this.defaultValue){
            this.value = '';
        }
        if(this.value != this.defaultValue){
            this.select();
        }
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated!

P.S - as you can see i already have noconflict() so don't try to suggest that cause it doesn't help in this case scenario.

Comment: The jQuery code i shown below and basically every jQuery code i try to run inside of the window.

Comment: What happens? What error messages do you get in the error console?

Comment: That's the problem.. there is no errors at all, it just doesn't work.. I also tried to do an Ajax call that works outside of the windows perfect and it just doesn't work with no errors. I think i need to do something similar to the JavaScript's "window." attachment.

Comment: WHat is `this.defaultValue`? Is this a custom attribute?

Comment: well, it doesn't matter because this code works outside of the window and it doesn't work inside (like every other jQuery script).

Answer (score 0):

give this a shot

```
var $jQ = jQuery;
$jQ(document).ready(function(){
    $jQ('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
        if (this.value == this.defaultValue){
            this.value = '';
        }
        else {
            this.select();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: nope buddy it doesn't work, i guess i will just re-code everything to use iframe as the content and not pull it by Ajax.